# Reputation in users list doesn’t reflect current filter for mobile web

Tags: bug, reputation, mobile-web, users-page

Despite on filter mode for reputation only the total [user reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week) is shown in mobile web:

> [image: mobile]

Full web reflects current filter:

> [image: full]